# Need assistance with Tclapp wrapping

Tags: tcl, wrapper, expect, activetcl

I am making this GUI'ed TCL script with ActiveTCL & Expect.

But for some reason Expect doesn't work with telnet that comes with windows 8 64bit, so I figured a way to use a custom telnet tcl script. It works fine, but I need now to wrap my script with the telnet script and some logo images into a single .exe to run without extra files in directory, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I click add files to the tclapp wrapper but it says file not found on the script when it tries to call for the telnet script.

Comment: The system telnet on Windows is marked as a system binary (special filesystem flag) and that makes it impossible to attach a debug engine to, which is how Expect-on-Windows works under the hood. Just so as you know.

Comment: Are you trying to run your telnet script as its own wrapped executable?

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap Tcl code into a single-file executable, everything goes inside. Scripts, libraries, any images (assuming you're making a GUI), the lot. Tcl transparently extracts things and pretends you've got a real filesystem. However, when you execute a program (whether via `exec`, `open |…` or `spawn`) then the OS *must* be involved as you are creating a subprocess — the OS is *always* involved in that, as process management is one of the main things that the OS kernel does — and it needs to have a real executable to run. If you have packaged up your telnet-replacement as its own single-file executable and stored it inside the parent process's VFS, you have to make that subordinate process executable real.

Copy the telnet-executable out to some location (e.g., to the temporary directory, which I think should be described in `$::env(TEMP)`) and execute that.

```
set realTelnetExe [file join $::env(TEMP) mytelnet.exe]
file copy .../the/stored/copy/mytelnet.exe $realTelnetExe

spawn $realTelnetExe
# ...
```

You probably want to `file delete` the copy once you're done using it.

***Relevant background material:***

- [comp.lang.tcl thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/AnpWHk58P3A)

Comment: I think we missunderstood each other my telnet is a script not an exe. I could try to find winxp telnet to use with it since it works well with active TCL but I cant make it work with w8 64bit telnet client